# Mulitple domains forword to one domain with one ssl certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have three domains x.com, x.net and x.org. Only x.com has a ssl certificate. I have only one
application. I want both x.net and x.org forward to x.com. I did it successfully if use a browse with http. When I type x.NET it goes to x.com then forwarding to x.com under httpS. But if I type '", it does forward to my application, but with ssl certificate warning. Is there anyway I can forward  to ?
Any information would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I belief this is a common issue. Many ISPs offer one free ssl certificate (I know there is let'sencrypt, but it is good for 90 days only, you need to renew it ofter). But many organizations have one application with more than one domains. There should be a solution. Thanks.

Comment: If it were possible to do a redirect before validating the SSL certificate, that would make it extremely easy for anyone to impersonate anyone else. The solution is to use valid certificates for all domains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single certificate provided that it is valid for all the domains you are using, that is its Subject Alternative Name field contains the other domains.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, a certificate must be presented for the requested url, if it (the url) does not match the CN in the certificate, browsers issue a warning.